# How to secure communications inside Azure?

Tags: linux, windows-server-2012, azure, security

I'm interested in knowing best practices for securing communications between a Linux VM and a Windows VM/Web Role.

So in the end, i need to communicate securely like so--

Linux VM < -- > Windows Web Role

I know that you can create public IPs for VMs, but i'm not sure i want to allow that-- is that opening up too much?

Specifically I am planning on hosting Redis/Elasticsearch on these VMs, if that helps at all.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you securing, and _from_ what?

Comment: Communication between a .NET program and a Linux VM running Redis. 

Can you guys give me a chance to respond before closing this out? If i knew everything about this i wouldn't need the help, you know?

Comment: @MichaelHampton come on--

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about Azure networks, but you could look at [Azure VPN](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/fundamentals/networking/). For us, we build our services on Amazon EC2, and we have firewall rules set to make sure only some of our machines can see others. The Azure firewall can allow that also (your Reddis/elasticsearch box should be locked down to only your internal boxes).